# Location of public files within Android app

Tags: android, webserver, embedded-jetty

I'm using `Spark` web server on an `Android app`. I would like to set the static file directory, `staticFileLocation("/public");`,  but I do not know where to that maps into the Android application file structure. Any idea?

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: I think that what I was looking for was the `assets` directory. Spark is still not recognized static files from there though.